# How to achieve good performance animations using only Web standards?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, html5-canvas

Without using Flash, how can I make a game with fair graphics performance using only web standards, preferably those available in latest browsers? I have looked into HTML 5 Canvas and into SVG, but both seems not designed to be animated, are they? Is it feasible to do small animated effects with them? What libraries can you suggest?

I have also looked into WebGL, the only API that seems to have some performance goals, but it seems too much for just simple animations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original questioner asked, "I have looked into HTML 5 Canvas and into SVG, but both seems not designed to be animated, are they?"  SVG absolutely supports animation; among others, my acquaintance David Dailey has written extensively http://srufaculty.sru.edu/david.dailey/svg/ on the topic.

One related point I want to make:  I often run across browsers that are only getting a tenth or even a hundredth of the graphics performance they could display with a minor configuration change or two http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/client/unleash-the-power-of-hardware-accelerated-html5-canvas.html#fbid=SlaaSNoY3Fg .

Comment: David Dailey mentions at the bottom of his article in the first link: "This site does business with companies mentioned in this article or associated with the technologies."

Answer (score 2):

> WebGL enables web content to use an API based on OpenGL ES 2.0 to
>   perform 3D rendering in an HTML canvas in browsers that support it.

From [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/WebGL/Getting_started_with_WebGL)

You may want to look at [this](http://sebleedelisle.com/2011/04/html5javascript-platform-game-optimised-for-ipad/). It is a game made in JavaScript. Actually there are a lot of examples for good rendering of 3d objects using canvas.

JavaScript, HTML5 canvas is a good choice to make a game.

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to [improve `<canvas>` performance](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/performance/).

Answer (score 0):

You should checkout this google tech talk:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_RRnyChxijA

The speaker talks about using HTML5, client/server side javascript, css, and canvas.

I agree, WebGL is probably overkill for simple animations.

Here are some animation frameworks:
http://sixrevisions.com/javascript/10-impressive-javascript-animation-frameworks/

Answer (score 0):

As others have said HTML5 with Javascript can be used to create games with fairly decent graphics. There's a table of HTML5-based game engines here: https://github.com/bebraw/jswiki/wiki/Game-Engines